# Girl creatively using magical portals

Tags: story-identification

This might be a bit unusual, as I'm looking for a web original story (unpublished, possibly even not finished, available freely somewhere on the internet).

From what I remember the main character was a Japanese girl (author flirted with magical girls tropes) in an approximation of current world who gained... well, magical powers. She was able to create portals. She had some kind of helper that was teaching her how to do so effectively, standardised usage - this maybe happened in a pocket dimension? There were other magical worlds, with elves and other creatures, there was a multi-dimensional power-play in the background...

Everything was sprinkled with scientific authenticity and thought - at one point her attack was using the pressure at the Mariana Trench, much thought was given to what the portals are actually stationary to etc.

Work was unfinished when I was reading it a year or two ago, and almost definitely is not older than 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This story is called Saga of Soul, and was originally published at http://www.sagaofsoul.com/. (still there as of this posting)

> Meet Eriko, an introverted, intellectual teenage girl with good intentions.
>
> Now, watch Eriko get caught in the middle of multiple simultaneous plots as fairies, demons, inter-dimensional empires, evil geniuses, immortal killers, cosmic horrors and more all make their move, and it's up to her to save the day.
>
> "Saga of Soul" tells the story of Eriko, A.K.A. Soul, as she strives to protect the world against all odds. Updated on an irregular basis.

The [TVTropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/SagaOfSoul) mentions the use of pressurized water:

> "Eriko uses them several impressive ways, such as weaponizing seawater through pressure and the Earth's rotation."

It was abandoned quite a while ago, and probably won't ever be finished [despite the author's claims otherwise](http://sagaofsoul.yuku.com/topic/49/Is-Saga-of-Soul-dead).